# Upload images without convert to string

Tags: java, android, image

I need to upload images and i want to show all of images in another page. I have tried to use volley, but it need to encode and decode to show all images. It made my application not responding when i decode all the string of images.

My questions are:

1. Are there any ways to upload images beside volley?
2. Are there any ways to upload images using volley without convert them to string (encode)?

Thanks

Comment: What is an image? An image file?

Comment: Yes, multiple image files

Comment: Besides volley there is another library OkHttp which upload image file in multipart ,if you dont wish to use volley for uploading images as string,use OkHttp for uploading images...for more check http://blog.aimanbaharum.com/2016/03/26/android-image-multi-part-upload/

Comment: Okay, i will try that, thanks for you answer

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it once by positing multi part file using **HttpUrlConnection**.

Basically you provide the image file input stream, the desired file name and the file's MIME type.

You can access the source code through this link:
https://github.com/MinaSamy/DailySelfie/blob/master/app/src/main/java/bloodstone/dailyselfie/android/utils/PostMultiPart.java

Comment: Thanks, i will try it